# Mongodb aggregation failure: "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'."

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to figure out why this code fails:

```
db.restaurants.drop();

db.restaurants.insertMany( [
  { "_id" : 1, "borough" : "Manhattan"},
] );

db.restaurants.createIndex({
  "borough": "text"
})

db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { $match: { $text: { $search: "a" } } },
  { $sort: {score: {"$meta": "textScore"}}},
  { $project: {"_id": true}},
])
```

Error output:

```
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'.",
        "code" : 16410,
        "codeName" : "Location16410"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:639:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:729:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1058:12
@(shell):1:1
```

I know it has something to do with the project statement...

Thank you in advance!

-daniel

Comment: Reduce the failing code to a single stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is almost similar to this [Mongodb 4.4.0 FieldPath field names may not start with](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63296885/8987128), and i have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66514986/8987128) with solution, The only difference is projection fields, and some use cases!

After lot of research i found a below instruction in general terms of find and aggregation functions [text-score-metadata-meta-textscore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/#text-score-metadata-meta-textscore) under **Usage In Projection** section,

> *The `{ $meta: "textScore" }` expression can be a part of the projection document to include the text score metadata.*
>
> **The `$meta` expression can be present in either an inclusion or an exclusion projection.**
>
> *If you set the expression to a field name that already exists in the document, the projected metadata value overwrites the existing value.*

Above the bold sentence clears, if you use `$project` stage after `$sort` stage the `score` or text index field `borough` should be ***inclusion or an exclusion***,

As per your try the solution:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { $match: { $text: { $search: "a" } } },
  { $sort: { score: { "$meta": "textScore" } } },
  { 
    $project: {
      "_id": true, // or _id: 1
      "borough": false // or borough: 0
    }
  },
  // or by default _id would be included
  /*
  { 
    $project: {
      "borough": false // or borough: 0
    }
  },
  */
  // or below will work but this will work as exclusion projection, so you need to specify your other fields to exclude,
  /* 
  { 
    $project: {
      "_id": true, // or _id: 1
      "score": false, // or score: 0
    }
  }
  */
  // or by default _id would be included
  /*
  { 
    $project: {
      "score": false, // or score: 0
    }
  },
])
```

---

There is other way as well, **I would recommend this way**

- swap `$project` and `$sort` stage,

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  { $match: { $text: { $search: "a" } } },
  { $project: { "_id": true } },
  { $sort: { score: { "$meta": "textScore" } } }
])
```

Comment: The other way you've mentioned, worked for me.